# gcloud sql connection not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-datastore, codeigniter-3

I have uploaded a **CodeIgniter** project on **google cloud APP engine** with **Flexible Environment**

Getting bellow error, while connecting the SQL Instance

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 518

application/config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<instance-connection-name>;dbname=<data-base-name>',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => USERNAME,
    'password' => PASSWORD,
    'database' => DATABASE,
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
    document_root: .

env_variables:
    MYSQL_USER: USER
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
    MYSQL_DSN: mysql:dbname=<database>;unix_socket=/cloudsql/<instance-connection-name>

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <instance-connection-name>
```

Comment: Are your Cloud SQL instance and Google App Engine application in the same project? Does the application deploys or you get this error while deploying?

Comment: Yes i am using Cloud SQL instance and Google App Engine application in the same project and no i am not getting any error while deploying. Error is coming from codeigniter, after deploying.

Comment: I am with Google Cloud support and I believe that this issue would be easier solved on Issue Tracker. So please go ahead and post your issue with your project number [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) and after the creation please comment the link to the post.

Comment: @komarkovich, Here is the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/111195161) to issue tracker.

Comment: Hi @parth did the suggestion from the PIT worked? Changing from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in 'hostname'.

Comment: @FedericoPanunzio, i did try your suggestion, but it didnt work.

Comment: @parth could you share the code in core/CodeIgniter.php?

Comment: @parth i don't really know how this CodeIgniter works, so could you try running the smaple code from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql) to rule out any issues with the Cloud SQL instance or proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Have experienced the same case with a Symfony 4 project. My findings on that:

When I first deployed the app on the App engine and the hostname was set:

'hostname' => 'localhost'

I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Afterwords I just removed the above line ('hostname' => 'localhost') and deployed the app again. This worked for me

On the next deployments I added again the hostname with localhost and it worked.

**Conclusion**

- First time deploy: remove/delete the hostname paremeter
- After first deploy you can use set the hostname ('hostname' => 'localhost') again